# How to make autogenerated model attribute id to always be a string

Tags: sails.js

I have an application which uses a Mongo database. I often use the ID of the records which are ObjectIds/strings like `507f1f77bcf86cd799439011`.

My issue is when I run my site i development mode, the Sails application is using in-memory store and uses numbers/interger as the objectId. That screws with my application.

I want Sails to always store the id as an string.
Whats the best way of dealing with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
In your config/models.js file, edit the default id attribute to have the 
appropriate type and columnName for MongoDB's primary keys:

attributes: {
   id: { type: 'string', columnName: '_id' },
   //…
 }

for more please follow the sails mongo docs: 
https:`//sailsjs.com/documentation/tutorials/using-mongo-db
```

Comment: When a model is created, the `id` column is auto generated. When adding those lines to `models.js` sails is expecting the `id` attribute with all the other attributes instead of autogenerating it.Like the example below, it is now missing the primary key.

`error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error: Trying to create an association on a model that doesn't have a Primary Key.`

Comment: can i look your config/models file and api/models/*file

Comment: The models files do not have an `id` attribute. They are generated automatically by the database. I made a workaround where I use a bash script to setup the development environment, including a MongoDB, instead of use the Sails on-disk feature.